# Barebone easy to use framework for not such basic site

Tags: web-development, framework

I am PHP dev, for more than 8 years working in a company that used Zend Framework as base for our sites. During those years I did not have time or interest to play with new frameworks. I will soon begin to develop a site that will need

1. blog for few editors
2. classifieds section
3. part of site that will be similar to Stack Exchange
4. user login - easy, i.e. Google of Facebook integration
5. many more modules aka widgets
6. maybe a forum

What would suite me perfect is a framework that has basic classes, for URL routing, DB connection, PHP standard template (or pick the one I prefer). Can support submodules of a site i.e. admin area, basically small sites in a main site.

It would be great if the framework can be used in jQuery spirit unlike ZF which in my opinion is too strict / complex / bloated. For example I would like for a DB class to have functionality similar to and same for other classes

```
DB::setConnection('whateverneeded');
$results = DB::getArray('select id form X where ?' , $Y);
or
DB::update($table,$where=array('X'=>$X,'Y'=>$Y , $data=array(K=>V .... );
```

It would be nice to have premade themes but it is not a priority and maybe some standard plugins. So basically bare-bone easy to use framework.

Also I am not strict to PHP though I prefer it. I hear a lot about Node.js but also hearing that it likes to eat memory a lot. Also is Django any good? Also I see lot of people asking on Stack Overflow "how to do XX in Laravel?".

Any input from users that had a chance to develop on such platform will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/) as a platform.

Liferay can be used "as is", but it is primarily designed for developers to implement their own plugins/templates or use existing ones.

I has tons of modules for blogs, FAQs, authentication, forums, and tons of other gadgets.

Of course, the API has everything you need for URL routing, database, etc.

The technology is Java and AlloyUI. Open source.